# React: Button click not writing to console

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, debugging

I have a button and for testing purposes, I want to write to the console the index of an array element. More specifically, I have a button in button.js, and that button is displayed on each array element in the IncomeOutputList array. When clicked on, I want each button to print to the console the index of the corresponding IncomeOutputList array element.
For example, by clicking on the button of the second element shown in the image below, I want the console to display index 1 (the first element is the topmost rectangle, which is a blank array element).

Here is a picture of an array element with the button, the button appears while hovering above the number for each array element:

[image]

Currently when the page renders, all of the indices of the array are displayed in console, not sure why.
I hope I made my question clear!

button.js:

```
import React from 'react';

const Button = ({buttonType, handler}) => (
    <>
        <div className="item__delete">
            <button className={buttonType} onClick={handler}>
                <i className="ion-ios-close-outline"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </>
)

export default Button;
```

ValueOutput.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '../buttons/Button';

//move item__value element to left when hovering over it, and make delete button appear

const ValueOutput = ({type, value, handleClick}) => {
    
    return (
        <>
            <div className="right clearfix">
                <div className="item__value">{type} {value}</div>
                <Button buttonType="item__delete--btn" handler={handleClick}/>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default ValueOutput;
```

IncomeOutput.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ValueOutput from './ValueOutput';

const IncomeOutput = ({ desc, type,id, value, handleButton }) => {
    //id = inc-{id}
        return (
            <>
                <div className="item clearfix income" id={id}>
                    <div className="item__description">{desc}</div>
                        <ValueOutput
                            type={type}
                            value={value}
                            handleClick={handleButton}
                        />
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }

export default IncomeOutput;
```

IncomeOutputList.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import IncomeOutput from './IncomeOutput';


// list will be list of income objects
const IncomeOutputList = ({ list }) => {

    const handler = (i) => {
        console.log(i);
        console.log('the test');
    }

    return (
        <div className="income__list">
            <div className="income__list--title">INCOME</div>
            {list.map((item, index) => <IncomeOutput 
                                id={item.id} 
                                value={item.incomeValue} 
                                type={item.budgetType} 
                                desc={item.desc} 
                                handleButton={handler(index)} 
                                />
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `handler(index)` as your event handler. Since that doesn't return anything you are effectively passing `undefined` as your handler. You will want to change  your handler method to return a function:

```
const handler = (i) => {
    return () => {
        console.log(i);
        console.log('the test');
    };
};
```

You could also just wrap your call to handler in a function, `buttonHandle={() => handler(index)}` - This is effectively the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `handler` function is executed right away when the code is encountered.

Whenever you have `()` the function will execute right away when encountered. It is not waiting for the event to fire.

Here is what you can do:

```
handleButton={() => handler(index)}
```